# EventBus communication between two Fragments. No subscriber error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, event-bus

I used EventBus for communication between Activity and Fragment without problems, however when I tired to do the same with two Fragments, EventBus notifies me that there has been no subscriber for given event. Here is a sample example of sending event from FragmentB to subscribed FragmentA:

**Sample FragmentA(Receiver, which doesn't receive a message):**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

private View mView;

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(int msg) {/* Do something */};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_fragment_layout, container, false);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
}
```

**Sample FragmentB(Sender):**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

private View mView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b_fragment_layout, container, false);
    sendMessage(1);
    return mView;
}

private void sendMessage(int msg){
    EventBus.getDefault().post(msg);
}
}
```

**Error which I get:**

```
No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

The problem seems to be quite simple, however I can't figure it out.

Comment: Problem is simple, FragmentA is not registered...

Comment: You must be hitting onStop before you receive the event

Comment: ...Or send message before registering..

Comment: Yes, I know that one Fragment is not registered, however what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, create a simple model class, let's call it `NotifyEvent`

```
public class NotifyEvent {
    public int mValue;

    public NotifyEvent(int value){
        this.mValue = value;
    }
}
```

and now sending and receiving should be like

in FragmentB:

```
private void sendMessage(int msg){
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotifyEvent(msg));
}
```

in FragmentA:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(NotifyEvent event){
        int msg = event.mValue;
        // do something with msg.
}
```

for details please go [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

Comment: He is already doing it, also he wrote that it's working with activity to fragment communication... So,  how this would help him?

Comment: @Selvin I wish people think before they talk or take any actions and stop thinking themselves as smartest ones. check OP's own answer, please.

Comment: The why didn't you wrote in the question that the problem is with primitive type? I wish people would give a full answer instead copying some tutorials

Comment: because I wasn't sure, but I thought my answer might help him.

Comment: Max! You are totally right!  It did work as well as any other objec to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. Funny thing, but **you are required to pass some MessageEvent object rather than int or another primitive type**. What I have done is simply posted a custom MessageEvent object which contained required parameters instead of raw integer:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new SomeObject(9));
```

**Instead of**

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(9);
```

Example of POJO:

```
public class SomeObject {
private int mTime;

public SomeObject(int time){
    this.mTime = time;
}

public int getTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setTime(int time) {
    this.mTime = time;
}
}
```

Hope it will help somebody!